# MD5 in Java, works with apostrophe (')

Tags: java, hash, md5

I'm trying to hash a string in java using MD5, and every solution I've found on SO doesn't handle the apostrophe character correctly. I've tried:

```
private static String getMD5(String input) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    final String md5Hex = md5Hex(input);
    return md5Hex;
}
```

Which uses the DigestUtils class. I've also tried the solution from https://dzone.com/articles/get-md5-hash-few-lines-java:

```
    private static String getMD5(String input) throws Exception {
       MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       m.update(input.getBytes(), 0, input.length());
       return new BigInteger(1, m.digest()).toString(16);
   }
```

But that doesn't work either. What solution in Java works for getting an MD5 hash with a string that may contain apostrophes and other special characters?

CLARIFICATION: the code above doesn't throw an error, it just generates the wrong MD5 checksum.

Comment: In what way does it fail to handle apostrophe? Also, using `BigInteger` is not the correct way to hex encode a `byte[]`.

Comment: I can't see an apostrophe in your example

Comment: Please explain what "doesn't handle the apostrophe character correctly" means. What did you do ? What happens ? What should happen ? Post some complete code that shows what you are trying to do, code that other people can compile and run.

Comment: You'll have to specify a character encoding to use for your method to be portable, e.g.: `s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`.

Comment: Apologies - I was unclear. The code does not throw an exception, it just does not calculate it correctly. It returns a result, but that result != the actual MD5 checksum as compared to several online MD5 tools.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

public class MDTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
       String s="This is 'a' test";
       MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       m.update(s.getBytes(),0,s.length());
       System.out.println("MD5: "+new BigInteger(1,m.digest()).toString(16));
   }
}
```

this prints MD5: a69bc3b6a061b79328910b8314d40e24

What error are you getting?

Comment: As per http://www.md5.cz/ and/or http://www.md5online.org/md5-encrypt.html, that isn't the right checksum. The correct checksum is:

Comment: e9e1324ed42c0cca9fb918114203f099